# HTML server control vs ASP.net web

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am trying to call a javascript function on click of a button (server control).When i use html button control (with a `runat="server"` attribute) for the above purpose, am able to do it ,
but when I use ASP.net Button control (web control), It gives me the
error: **BC30456: 'myFunction' is not a member of 'ASP.webform1_aspx'.**

What  is the difference ?

For case 1 my code using html button control, case 2 is my code using ASP.net  web control:

**case 1:**

```
<html>
     <head>
     <script >
     function myFunction()
     {
     alert("Hello World!");
     }
     </script>
     </head>

     <body>
     <button runat="server" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
     </body>
     </html>
```

** case 2:**

```
<html>
     <head>
     <script >
     function myFunction()
     {
     alert("Hello World!");
     }
     </script>
     </head>

     <body>

    <asp:Button id="Button"  onclick="myFunction()" runat="server" Text="Button" />
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: your asp:button is missing "<"

Comment: @Zaki, that was a typo, i have actually used : <asp:Button id="Button"  onclick="myFunction()" runat="server" Text="Button" />

Answer (score 1):

When you write runat="server" it becomes the server control and to call JS function with server side control you have to use OnClientClick instead of OnClick method.
If you use Onclick method it will try to find the function on server.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks Umar, it was helpful. Any idea why it worked for case 1? there also we had a server control with Onclick..

Comment: Hey in case 1 you are creating an html control. browser identifies it first and it tries to look for js function but when you mention explicitly that its a webserver control then it renders the control in that way. To understand more about it you have to look for rendered source in the browser for both cases. (right click browser view source :)) you will see the difference. Mark it correct if it helps

Answer (score 0):

use onClientClick for asp control

Actually onClick searches a method in your aspx.cs file, ie a C# or VB function

http://forums.asp.net/t/1249580.aspx?onclick+versus+onclientclick

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: so u mean it works fine for html server control but for asp.net web control it searches for the method in my .vb file?

Comment: yes, exactly, When your asp control is rendered to html control thats what it does, it appends the functionality of your vb code or what ever your backend is, if you nedd to call js function use onclientclick